unable to find the xpath for <br> tag in selenium
 Tag
for this xpath i am getting error.
//div[contains(@class,'box-information')]/div[@class='box-content']//br

Print the user details:[[[ChromeDriver: chrome on windows (48039663d8c26742c7adce0da156e340)] -> xpath: //div[contains(@class,'box-information')]/div[@class='box-content']]]
PASSED: actPanelTest
FAILED: getUserInforDetailsTest
java.lang.AssertionError: Lists differ at element [0]: joshna g joshna@gmail.com != [[ChromeDriver: chrome on windows (48039663d8c26742c7adce0da156e340)] -> xpath: //div[contains(@class,'box-information')]/div[@class='box-content']] expected [joshna g joshna@gmail.com] but found [[[ChromeDriver: chrome on windows (48039663d8c26742c7adce0da156e340)] -> xpath: //div[contains(@class,'box-information')]/div[@class='box-content']]].
Could you anyone please help me how to fetch the data.,  I am not able to write the xpath for  tag this is the testing url

Using the testing url there are no elements with those classes.
